# Sorting five plates

Tags: mathematics, optimization

You have a stack of 5 plates of different sizes as shown in the left figure below. In each move you can pick up the top k plates (k is from 1 to 5) and flip them over. For example, if you do this with the top 3 plates you will get the result shown in the right figure below.

[image]

What is the least number of moves needed to reverse the order of the plates, while keeping them the right way up, as shown in the following figure?

[image]

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X79900682 Yes, *that* Bill Gates.

Comment: Related: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95008/stacking-pancakes-for-your-wife

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 9 moves by reversing 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4 plates respectively.

> Denoting the plates as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 right way up and as 1R, 2R, 3R, 4R, 5R when upside down, after each operation we get these configurations:
>  **4R 3R 2R 1R** 5
>  **5R 1 2 3 4**
> **3R 2R 1R 5** 4
>  **4R 5R 1 2 3**
>  **2R 1R 5 4** 3
>  **3R 4R 5R 1 2**
>  **1R 5 4 3** 2
>  **2R 3R 4R 5R 1**
>  **5 4 3 2** 1

> My approach was to consider every possible arrangement of plates as a state, then we can have no more than 10x8x6x4x2 = 3840 possible states, then use breadth first search to find shortest path to the desired state. [Code](https://pastebin.com/raw/gWNMvffW)

Edit:

> For any n > 1 number of starting plates, we can reverse the order of plates using 2n-1 steps: flip n-1, n, n-1, n, ..., n-1, n, n-1 plates. This appears to be the minimal answer.

Comment: Beautiful code.

Comment: Nice to know about the generalization!